# Angular.js beginner: Is Yeoman scaffolding the wrong way to go?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add Angular to my arsenal and just started playing around with it this weekend. Looks cool!

In one of the videos done by Google, the guy recommended Yeoman. I'm watching another tutorial video on it now as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqdRXqeqgZs

However, it looks like it generates everything (even writes tests for you??). In the video above, to generate a route he ran `yo angular:route myroute` which generated the controller, route, view, and test. I mean it's great that I get to see the structure, but I wrote like 0 lines of code.

Perhaps I should just start off with something like this where the file structure is way simpler but at least I have to write more lines of code? https://github.com/davidb583/white-angularjs-app

For a beginner, which do you recommend for a first project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a beginner to AngularJS, don't check out Yeoman. It's a very useful tool remember, but before you use it, understand why it was built.

Start off with AngularJS's [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) - it is one of the best tutorials out there. It tells you all that you need to know to explore off on your own. I started out with that and at the end of it, I just loved the entire framework.

I did not start off with Yeoman until building 2-3 applications using AngularJS. Once you do this, you figure out some common tasks that you carry out for every AngularJS application.

That's where Yeoman comes in. Rather than doing the same thing again and again for each application you use Yeoman to automate a lot of stuff. Once you know the *why* of using Yeoman, you will understand the *how* of using it.

Without having worked in AngularJS sufficiently, do not try to use Yeoman. You will enjoy the tool but then you will be left wondering how to work with AngularJS without it.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

To smalls app, Yeoman is awesome. But you will know his limits when you will want to split your app into modules.

with yeoman, you will have a structure like that:

```
scripts/
  controllers
     controller1.js
     controller2.js
     ...
  directive/
  ...
```

But In large app you probably want to have:

```
scripts/
  controllers
     userModule
        controller.js
     myOtherModule
        controller.js
     ...
  directive/
  ...
```

And for that, you need to create manually all the files.
My advice is to always start with yeoman but use their route/directive/etc generator only at the begining of your project.

For the tests, it only generate a file and a very simple test, ofcourse you need to modify it, to cover your whole app.

In addition Yeoman provide you a lot of tools with grunt like minifications of your assets, a jshint to use the best coding practices, etc.

Comment: Great I'm just going to copy the same structure as the github repo I pasted in and do everything manually first. Thanks!